# Jenkins prevent specific jobs from building during defined time frame

Tags: jenkins

I've got two Jenkins jobs, a continuous integration job that runs whenever a new change is submitted, and a build/deploy job that runs everyday at noon. I do not want the builds to run simultaneously, so I am using the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin to force only these two jobs to queue up if either of them is already running. Any of my other jobs are allowed to run at the same time as these two jobs.

I would like the build/deploy job to always run at noon, but sometimes a developer submits a change just before noon causing the build/deploy job to wait until the CI job finishes.

Is there a way to block only the CI job during a defined time frame, like 11:30am until 1pm, so that the build/deploy job will not be blocked at noon?

Comment: interesting question; I use ant script to lock 2 concurrent jobs. I write a file if the file exists the job exit with error. However I'm going to test the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin on my CI. I'll reply ASAP

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the are few possibilities:

- a first pre-step which check the date and exit with error if the date do NOT match the requirements
- two jobs which disable and enable the job programmatically calling the REST

eg job 1

```
curl -X POST http://usr:pwd@host/job/joobname/disable
```

and job 2

```
curl -X POST http://usr:pwd@host/job/joobname/enable
```

at given time.

Comment: Wouldn't the first option create a bunch of "failed" builds in the job build history? As for the second option, I am using the Job Configuration History plugin, and enabling/disabling the job everyday would fill up the job config history (I should ask how to prevent that in a separate question).

Comment: Add "if [ `date +%k` -ge 22 ] || [ `date +%k` -le 5 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi;" as a pre-build step. It prevents builds from starting between 10:00pm and 6:00am. Builds might still run during the quiet period if they started at e.g.: 9:59pm. Builds attempting to start during the quiet period will be marked as failed indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add slave node which is offline from 11:30am until 1pm and restrict change-caused build to this.

Second possibility is to enable SCM poll schedule to check for changes during allowed time-frame.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I went with modifying the SCM poll schedule:

    `H/15 0-10,12-23 * * *`

So the CI job polls for changes every 15 minuts between midnight and 10:59am, then noon to midnight, skipping the hour before noon.